# Jackson XML Serialization: Nested Element with Same Name as Parent

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind, jackson2, jackson-dataformat-xml

I have a complex xml type with a nested element whose name is the same as the parent, but when I serialize it the nested element gets set as the text of the parent when it is included in another element.

The DTOs looks like this:

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "address")
public class Address{
    @JacksonXmlText(false)
    @JsonProperty
    private String address;
    @JsonProperty
    private String city;
    //getters and setters
}

@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "person")
public Person {
    private String name;
    private Address address;
}
```

My XmlMapper configuration:

```
XmlMapper xmlMapper = XmlMapper.xmlBuilder()
    .defaultUseWrapper(false)
    .serializationInclusion(NON_NULL)
    .build();
xmlMapper.getFactory()
    .getXMLOutputFactory()
    .setProperty("javax.xml.stream.isRepairingNamespaces", false);
```

When I serialize an Address on it's own, I get the expected value:

```
<address><address>123 East Street</address><city>metropolis</city></address>
```

But when I serialize an Address as a nested object of another DTO, like Person, then the address property is serialized as text of the Address parent object.

Actual XML:

```
<person><address>123 East Street<city>metropolis</city></address></person>
```

Expected XML:

```
<person><address><address>123 East Street</address><city>metropolis</city></address></person>
```

I already know that this is just **bad** XML design, but that is what I have to do!

Any ideas on how to get the expected XML output?

#### Edits

I found a workaround by creating another DTO with a "value" field marked as text.

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "address")
public class StreetAddress{
    @JacksonXmlText
    private String value;
    //getters and setters
}
//snip
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "address")
public class Address{
    @JsonProperty
    private StreetAddress address;
    @JsonProperty
    private String city;
    //getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When wiring the DTOs like follows, the XML output is produced like expected. I used version `2.10` of `jackson-annotations` and `jackson-dataformat-xml`. No differences to the code except additional getters and setters.

```java
Address a = new Address();
a.setCity("metropolis");
a.setAddress("123 East Street");
Person p = new Person();
p.setAddress(a);
xmlMapper.writeValue(new PrintWriter(System.out), p);
```

Output

```
<person><address><address>123 East Street</address><city>metropolis</city></address></person>
```

Comment: I'll have to setup a better example project, since I am definitely still getting that error. I did find a work around, which I will add as an edit.

Comment: I think it might be that I am using the oracle stax implementation instead of woodstox (also a requirement).